# What are direct and indirect deprecations in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony

https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/phpunit_bridge.html talks about direct deprecations and indirect deprecations but doesn't define what these terms mean.

I can't find anything on Google about them either. It looks like a term Symfony have invented, but aren't explaining.

Answer (score 0):

From [same documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/phpunit_bridge.html#direct-and-indirect-deprecations):

> The `max[direct]` config allows you to put a threshold on **direct deprecations only**, allowing you to notice when *your code* is using deprecated APIs

So from that we can say that:

- *Direct deprecations* are the ones that is directly in your own code and that you can change. E.g. `App\Services\MySuperService@1334` is using deprecated method and you can change it immediately.
- *Indirect deprecations* are the ones that is in dependencies and you can't fix them on your own. E.g. `Symfony\HtmlChecker\PhpHtmlChecker` is using `Faro\Baron\Services\Html::fontTagCheck` that is deprecated and you must wait for Symfony PhpHtmlChecker code base update to fix that deprecation

Comment: So indirect ones are ones that are caused by code in /vendor ?

Comment: @joachim Usually yes. For any code that you have no control over

Comment: How does Symfony define that -- for instance, what about packages which Composer installs to a different location?

Comment: @joachim _How defines that_ - look at code, I don't know. Maybe anything that is downloaded via any package manager (or just Composer) is treated as external source

Comment: So basically, it's undocumented :/

Comment: @joachim First time? :D

Comment: Not sure what you mean - my first time on SO, or my first time encountering undocumented code? No to both! :)